# Tap on ParentViewController closes the ChildViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController which has add button which will open SideBarVC on right side of screen.
If I tap on my main ViewController screen again It should close my SideBarVC.

I tried

```
@IBAction func click_leistung(_ sender: UIButton) {

    leistungList = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "leistungVC") as! leistungVC
    leistungList.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    leistungList.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
         self.present(leistungList, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    self.myscrollView.endEditing(false)
   leistungList.removeFromParentViewController()
    leistungList = nil
}
```

Comment: In your code you're instantiating a new controller and then removing it from its parent, I don't think that's quite what you want to do. You should probably share the part of the code where you open that "SideBarVC" so we understand how it gets added in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you trying to remove fresh VC, but you should store pointer to old one to remove it. Create var to store pointer to this leistungList and then remove it from parent.

```
var storedController: UIViewController?
func show() {
    // ...
    storedController = presentedController
}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    // Das keyboard ist weg
    self.myscrollView.endEditing(false)
    storedController.removeFromParentViewController()
    storedController = nil
}
```

PS: read this article to understand how to manage child controllers https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: I tried this , its not working. Flow is not reaching touchesBegan().